# Annualised timeseries over multiple years

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data set that  looks like this

```
2012-01-01     0.1
2012-01-02     0.2
2012-01-03     1.2
....
2016-01-01     0.9
```

Instead of calculating a basic arithmetic mean I would like to calculate an annualised mean over the whole time period. Is there an elegant way of doing this in R?

Currently my data is stored as a R zoo object.

Comment: maybe `sum(myZoo)/as.integer(end(myZoo) - start(myZoo) + 1)` or `xts::apply.yearly(myZoo, mean)` depending on the outcome you are looking for.

Comment: You should post code that at least creates an object. Just posting a "looks like" abbreviation of an object is not really very helpful. You should also say in more carefully constructed fashion what you expect to see as "an annualised mean over the whole time period". Is that a mean of the annual means or is that 4 means, one for each  for each annual interval (less the terminating date).  And is "annualized" a geometric mean or an arithmetic mean.